# Find and replace part of dictionary values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I have a python dictionary and I would like to find and replace part of the characters in the values of the dictionary. I'm using python 2.7.
My dictionary is

```
data1 = {'customer_order': {'id': '20'},
         'patient': 
             {'birthdate': None,
             'medical_proc': None,
             'medical_ref': 'HG_CTRL12',
             'name': 'Patient_96',
             'sex': None},
          'physician_name': 'John Doe'
         }
```

I would like to change the underscore to backslash underscore only in the values of the dictionary, in this case only for Patient_96 and HG_CTRL12.

I would like to change it to the following:

```
 data1 = {'customer_order': {'id': '20'},
          'patient': 
              {'birthdate': None,
               'medical_proc': None,
               'medical_ref': 'HG\_CTRL12',
               'name': 'Patient\_96',
               'sex': None},
          'physician_name': 'John Doe'
         }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What should Patient_96 be changed to? Your question says, change `'_'` to `'_'`. I do not see the difference?

Comment: Sorry but the underscore were omitted from my question

Comment: It may make it more clear if you post a "before and after" of the data.

Comment: @JoanaRosadoCoelho Even the current edit does not make sense. What does "I would like to change the underscore to \underscore" mean?

Comment: I'm usually all about questions being as precise as possible, but what exactly the replacement string is doesn't really matter here, does it? The tricky part is recursively dealing with nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function recursively replaces the underscore in the values of the dictionary with `replace_char`:

```
def replace_underscores(a_dict, replace_char):
    for k, v in a_dict.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            if v and '_' in v:
                a_dict[k] = v.replace('_', replace_char)
        else:
            replace_underscores(v, replace_char)
```

More on `isinstance()` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for i in data1:
...     if type(data1[i]) is str:
...             if data1[i]:
...                     data1[i] = data1[i].replace('_','\_')
...     elif type(data1[i]) is dict:
...             for j in data1[i]:
...                     if data1[i][j]:
...                             data1[i][j] = data1[i][j].replace('_','\_')
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> data1
{'physician_name': 'John Doe', 'customer_order': {'id': '20'}, 'patient': {'medical_ref': 'HG\\_CTRL12', 'medical_proc': None, 'name': 'Patient\\_96', 'birthdate': None, 'sex': None}}
```